# How on earth can I get a custom WP REST API endpoint to check for authorised access while my accessing application uses OAuth 1.0a Server credentials?

Tags: php, wordpress, oauth, wordpress-rest-api

OK, so here's my issue. I'm building a Laravel application (5.4) which makes API calls to my website's Wordpress CMS (running version 4.9.8).

Most of these API calls are unsecure requests to retrieve basic HTML content etc, from custom endpoints I've built and these endpoints live in a custom WP plugin I'm also building. Here's an example of one of these custom endpoints, calling a menu's (via slug) buffering the function and then returning the buffered HTML content as a JSON object.

To access this unsecured custom endpoint, the example URL would be

http://example.com/wp-json/custom-api/v1/items/menu/{menu-slug-goes-here}

And the code in the plugin which asserts this unsecured custom API endpoint would be...

```
function get_menu(WP_REST_Request $request) {
    ob_start();
    wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => $request['slug'], 'container' => false));  
    $menu = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return rest_ensure_response($menu);
}


add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'custom-api/v1/items/', 'menu/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z-]+)', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'get_menu',
     'args' => array(
          'slug' => array(
            'validate_callback' => function($slug, $request, $key) {
              return is_string( $slug );
            }
          ),
        ),
      ) );
    } );
```

So far so good. This unsecured endpoint works fine.

Until we get into setting up a custom API endpoint that would require Oauth1 authentication. Say perhaps the Laravel application needs to call customer data from via a secure custom API endpoint.

After days of researching, I can't figure this out, so I wondered if someone could please offer me some advice?

Before we get started, it's worth noting;

1. According to the WP API documentation, authentication is primarily done via cookies, but the user will need to be logged in for this to happen? Or a AJAX request can be made using a nonce. Here's the link to the docs;

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

2. I'm using Wordpress REST API - OAuth 1.0a Server (link below) plugin to manage the Laravel application's authentication. This has all be done, the Laravel app is authorised, it has its consumer keys, secrets and permanent tokens and these have been tested and are able to access WP's secure baked-in API endpoints, like /wp/v2/settings

https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api-oauth1/

3. Wordpress API states that you can use 'permission_callback' functionality in combination with 'current_user_can' method to check the authentication via the (here's WP's official example)

   ```
   add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
   register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', '/author/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
   'methods' => 'GET',
   'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
   'args' => array(
     'id' => array(
       'validate_callback' => 'is_numeric'
     ),
   ),
   'permission_callback' => function () {
     return current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' );
    }
    ) );
   } );
   ```

So my question(s) is...

A) Can a function be created that will require and check Oauth1 credentials at the custom endpoint?

B) If not, can the application find a way to offer its status as a user and then from there, the 'current_user_can' can be called?

C) Or is their another solution that I'm totally missing???

Many thanks for your help, all constructive and good natured advice is appreciated!

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi timmah thank, sadly I didn't :(